# How to create a background thread on Windows 10

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-10

In Windows 8.1, we can simply do the following to run some code in background:

```
Task.Run(()=>{
    // running in background
});
```

But looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.105).aspx), it seems that the **Task Class** is no longer supported under Windows 10? Is it that they didn't update the documentation or there is a different method I should use?

> **Windows Phone OS** 
>   Supported in: 8.1, 8.0

Comment: That link you posted is to Windows Phone Silverlight APIs. Task is available on Windows 10. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Tim, thanks! I think you are right. The document is a bit confusing there. BTW, is **.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5** always equivalent to Windows 10 ? Is is safe to make the assumption that whatever is available under **.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5** is always save to use under Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, that is a safe assumption since it is a feature of the framework, not the OS, unless it specifically says that it isn't supported on some OS. For example, 4.5 is not supported on Windows XP, so therefore no features of 4.5+ are available on XP.